# Copy and paste data from different worksheets

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm trying to use VB script to copy the data in excel sheet1 to sheet2.
The problem is that I would like to paste the copied data, starting in A1 and push the current data in A1 to the bottom of the new data. My code so far just over rights, take a look below:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(CurrentDirectory & "\test.xlsx")
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B9").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B9").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Insert -4121
```